# How to get token after link generated on email after verifying email and register a user?

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, access-token

When a user registers, a link is sent to that email to get verified and when that user clicks on that link, then user gets verified and a new tab opens which gives message of email verification,then a JWT token would be generated after clicking on that link, so how do I get the token as I have api of token_generate(GET api).

Answer (score 1):

This should be the process as per my experience:

1. The user fills the registration form and submits
2. The backend API is called, the backend API creates a temporary verification token in the database against the email. For example something like this:

```js
{
  email: 'ahsanayaz@something.com',
  verificationToken: '123123123'
}
```

3. Then the backend sends the email to the user with a link like this:
   `https://yourfrontendapp.com/verify-user?verificationToken=123123123`
4. When the user clicks on the link from the email, the user basically opens a page within the frontend application. The front-end application extracts out the `verificationToken` query parameter from the current URL and sends it in another API call to the backend.
5. The backend receives the token and verifies it in the database (see step 2). Once the backend verifies it, the backend creates the user in the db, and it also generates the JWT token and sends back the user and the JWT token in the API call's response.
6. The user is still on the page `https://yourfrontendapp.com/verify-user?verificationToken=123123123` from where the API call was made in Step 4. The app receives back the JWT token and the user data from the verification API call now, and you save the JWT token and the user in localStorage or something and change the state of the frontend app to reflect that the user is now created and logged in.